# Volterra Operator is compact but has no eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Volterra operator is defined as operator $V:L^2[0,1]\rightarrow L^2[0,1]$ by 
\begin{eqnarray}
(V)(f(x))=\int_0^xf(y)dy
\end{eqnarray}
Would you help me to prove that this operator is compact but has no eigenvalues.

Comment: <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/spectrum-of-indefinite-integral-operators>

Comment: I noticed that you used `eqnarray` for your math. [Don't do that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Note that
$$
Vf(x)=\int_0^1f(t)k(x,t)\,dt,
$$
where $k(x,t)=1_{[0,x]}(t)$. It is a general fact that such an operator is Hilbert-Schmidt (and in particular compact) if and only if $k\in L^2([0,1]^2)$. Or one can show that the measurable function $k$ is a uniform limit of simple functions, and these simple functions can be used as kernels to define operators that approximate $V$. As these operators are finite-rank, $V$ is compact.

As for the eigenvalues, if $\lambda\ne0$ and $Vf=\lambda f$, then we get
$$\tag{1}
f(x)=\frac1\lambda\,\int_0^xf(t)\,dt.
$$
Using that $f$ is in $L^2$ we have, for $x<y$,
\begin{align}
|f(y)-f(x)|&=\frac1{|\lambda|}\,\left|\int_x^yf(t)dt\right|\leq\frac1{|\lambda|}\,\int_x^y|f(t)|dt=\frac1{|\lambda|}\,\int_0^1|f(t)|\,1_{[x,y]}(t)\,dt\\ &\leq\frac{\|f\|_2}{|\lambda|}\,\left(\int_0^1(1_{[x,y]})^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}=\frac{\|f\|_2}{|\lambda|}\,\sqrt{y-x}.
\end{align}
So $f$ is continuous. Then looking at (1) again we get that $f$ is differentiable; thus, after differentiation, (1) is the equation $f=\lambda f'$. This implies that $f(t)=c\,e^{ t/\lambda}$. But $f(0)=0$, so the only solution for (1) is $f=0$, and  $\lambda$ cannot be an eigenvalue.

The case $\lambda =0$ is trivial: if $Vf=0$, then  $f=0$.

Comment: Excellent answer. +1.