# Bounded linear operator on Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces

For all $f\in C[0,1]$ and $x\in[0,1]$ we define bounded linear operator
$$(Tf)(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x f(t)dt,$$ with norm $||T||=2$ (right?). 
I have already determined its image
$imT:=\{g\in C^1[0,1]| g'(0)=g(0)\} $.
Question:
Is $imT$ Banach space with respect to the norm $||.||_\infty$?
Prove $imT$ is infinite dimensional.
Find all eigenvalues of $T$.

If $T$ is bounded from below (i.e. $\exists M.||Tx||\geq M||x|| \quad \forall x$), then $imT$ is closed. ([When is the image of a linear operator closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/when-is-the-image-of-a-linear-operator-closed))

Is $T$ any different than Volterra operator: [Volterra Operator is compact but has no eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219699/volterra-operator-is-compact-but-has-no-eigenvalue)

For eigenvalues I suspect it has none.