# Volterra Bounded Operator

Tags: linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I have looked at the proofs in :
[Norm of integral operator in $L_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155899/norm-of-integral-operator-in-l-2?fbclid=IwAR2ykRh8S4GczP3M-GkPerFSM_NG4gt2Li7dMh-Xil5RpGpzyu0OT_TICMs)
and Halmos' solution to problem 188 but i wanted to find a more relaxed bound of the volterra operator without using the Hilbert adjoint operator. $$(Vx)(t)=\int_0^tx(s)ds$$ $ V : L^2(0,1)\to L^2(0,1)$, $t \in [0,1]$, $x \in L^2(0,1)$ .
**I need to use the Cauchy Shwartz Inequality to prove that $||V||\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ .**
I have already tried finding the norm using the following equation$$||||=\frac{||||}{||||}$$  and with 
$$||||=sup||||$$ with $||x||=1$ using the $L_2$ norm. But these solutions tend to provide little insight without any manipulations.

Comment: Where have you tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I tried using it in the inner product definition of cauchy shwartz. I did not think about the integral cauchy shwartz equivalent

Comment: Those are actually the same, as we can take the $L^2$ inner product $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz we have

$$ \vert (Vx)(t) \vert =\left\vert \int_0^t x(s) ds \right\vert \leq \int_0^t 1\cdot \vert x(s) \vert ds
\leq \left( \int_0^t 1 ds \right)^\frac{1}{2} \left( \int_0^t \vert x(s) \vert^2 ds \right)^\frac{1}{2} \leq \sqrt{t} \Vert x \Vert_{L^2(0,1)}$$
Therefore, we get
$$ \Vert Vx \Vert_{L^2(0,1)} = \left( \int_0^1 \vert (Vx)(t) \vert^2 dt \right)^\frac{1}{2}
\leq  \left( \int_0^1 t \ dt \right)^\frac{1}{2} \Vert x \Vert_{L^2(0,1)}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Vert x \Vert_{L^2(0,1)}$$
Hence, we get $$ \Vert V \Vert \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$

Comment: Thanks! This more than answers my question.

Comment: Glad I could help :)