# Functional law of iterated logarithm for integral of square of Brownian motion

Tags: definite-integrals, stochastic-processes, normed-spaces, brownian-motion, calculus-of-variations

Let $W$ be a Wiener process. Prove that the upper limit 
$$\limsup_{T\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^TW^2(s)\,ds}{T^2\ln\ln T}$$
is non-random (with probability 1) and calculate it.
I know that I have to use Strassen's law of iterated logarithm, so that this limit is 
$$\sup_{f\in K}\int_0^1f^2(s)ds$$
where  $K$ is the class of absolutely continuous functions such that $\int_0^1(f'(s))^2ds<1$ and $f(0)=0$, I can find some bounds for this supremum using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I can't find exact value.

Comment: In other words, you have to calculate the norm of the operator $h \mapsto \int_0^\cdot h(s) ds$ in $L^2[0,1]$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155899/norm-of-integral-operator-in-l-2) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/spectrum-of-indefinite-integral-operators).