Upper bound for integral operator from $L_2[0, 1] \to L_2[0, 1]$
How can we bound the norm of integral operator $H$ in $L_2[0,1] \to L_2[0, 1]$?
$H=\int_0^tx(\tau)d\tau$

what do you know about the norm of $x(\tau)$ ?

@Dowdow, I know the definition of operator norm that uses supremum: $$||A|| = \sup_{||x|| = 1}{||Ax||}$$ I guess I can not say something about norm of $x(\tau)$ using it..

you should include your attempt

This is the well-known Volterra operator, which has norm $\frac{2}{\pi}$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155899/norm-of-integral-operator-in-l-2?rq=1 for details.

Alex Pozzi's comment was what I had in mind. Getting a tight upper bound as Zarrax describes is another matter entirely.

It should be noted that $$\int_0^t |x(\tau)|\, d\tau \leq \int_0^1 |x(\tau)|\, d\tau$$ since $t\in [0,1]$.
Furthermore, using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have: $$\int_0^1 |x(\tau)|\, d\tau\leq \left(\int_0^1 1^2\, d\tau\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1 |x(\tau)|^2\, d\tau\right)^{1/2}=\|x\|_{L^2}.$$
Thus, we arrive at
$$\|H(x)\|^2_{L^2}=\int_0^1|H|^2\, ds=\int_0^1\left|\int_0^t x(\tau)\, d\tau\right|^2\, ds \leq \|x\|^2_{L^2},$$
where the continuity constant of the linear operator equals to $C:=1.$
From where it is seen that the opeator norm $\|H\|\leq 1$. To arrive at the other inequality, you must consider a function or a sequence of functions in $L^2([0,1])$ such that $\|H\|\geq 1$.

One does not in fact have $||H|| \geq 1$. The operator is the Volterra operator, which has norm $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get $$|(Hx)(t)|^2\le \int\limits_0^t\,d\tau\  \|x\|_2^2=t\|x\|_2^2$$ Thus $$\|Hx\|_2^2\le  \int\limits_0^1t\,dt\,\|x\|_2^2={1\over 2}\|x\|_2^2$$ Thus $\|H\|\le 2^{-1/2}.$ For $x(t)=1$ we obtain $(Hx)(t)=t$ and $\|x\|_2=1,$ $\|Hx\|_2=3^{-1/2}.$ Hence $\|H\|\ge 3^{-1/2}.$

@Zarrax Thanks for spotting the error.
