# singular value decomposition of the volterra operator

Tags: svd

Can anyone help me to this question?

Compute the singular value decomposition of the Volterra operator

$Tu(x) = \int_{0}^{x} u (s) ds$ in $L^2(0,1)$ and use it to find $\|T\|$. Is $T$ normal ?

Thank you

Comment: i try to do like this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330786/singular-value-decomposition-of-a-specific-integraloperator but i dont understand the eigenvalue and eigenfunctions calculate. therefore i couldnt continue for singular value decomposition operations

Comment: @nmb The calculations in the question body of the question you link are wrong. I added an answer with the correct calculations.