# Showing an operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Can someone please explain to me how I can show the following operator is compact?
$$ Af(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$
where $A:L_2[0,1]\rightarrow L_2[0,1]$.

There are two definitions of compactness that I've encountered:

Def1. An operator $L$ is compact if for a bounded sequence $\{ x_n\}$, there exists a convergent subsequence $\{ x_{n_k}\}_k$.

Def2. An operator $L$ is compact if it's continuous and maps a bounded set to a sequentially compact set.

What is the easier/standard method to prove compactness for integral operators?

I also know that "If $L$ is a bounded linear operator on a separable Hilbert space, with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, and $\sum_n\| L e_n\|^2<\infty$, then $L$ is compact. "

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/spectrum-of-indefinite-integral-operators

Comment: @cmk Thank you. There's an easier way I think though. $L$ is a  linear operator and satisfies $\sum_n\| L e_n|<\infty$. If I show it's bounded I can use my very last argument in the question. How can I prove it's bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $A$ is bounded, Cauchy-Schwarz works well
$$
    \|Af\|^2 = \int_0^1\left|\int_0^x f(t)dt\right|^2dx \\
    \le \int_0^1 \int_0^x|f(t)|^2dt\int_0^xdt\,dx \\
     = \int_0^1 \int_0^x|f(t)|^2dt xdx \\
     \le \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |f(t)|^2dt \, 1 dx = \|f\|^2.
$$
Then apply your theorem using the orthonormal basis $\{ e_n(t)= e^{2\pi int} \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$:
$$
          Ae_n = \int_0^x e_n(t)dt = \frac{1}{2\pi in}(e_n(t)-1), \; n\ne 0, \\
            \|Ae_n\|\le \frac{1}{\pi|n|},\;\; n\ne 0.
$$

Comment: Couldn't you just use $$
    \|Af\|^2 = \int_0^1\left|\int_0^x f(t)dt\right|^2dx  
    \le \int_0^1 \int_0^x|f(t)|^2dt dx  
$$

Comment: @Teodorism : I not only used that, I derived it with Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is an integral operator with kernel $K(x,t) = \mathsf1_{(0,x)}(t)$ and
$$
\iint_{[0,1]^2} |K(x,t)|^2\ \mathsf d(x\times t) = \int_0^1\int_0^x\ \mathsf dt \ \mathsf dx = \frac 12<\infty,
$$
so $K\in L^2([0,1]^2)$. It follows that $A$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator and therefore is compact.