# Is this operator compact in $L^2[0,d]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Consider $X=L^2[0,d]$ and define $A \colon X \to X$ a linear bounded operator by the integral function
\begin{equation}
 {A}x=\int_0^\cdot x(\xi)d\xi
\end{equation}
This operator looks compact to me since its range $R(A) \subset W^{1,2}$ which is continuously embedded with compact embedding into $X$. Is this true? How can I formalize the details?

Comment: This is the Volterra operator. One way to see that $A$ is compact, is to realise that it is a Hilbert--Schmidt operator. A more direct way to prove compactness is to apply the Arzela--Ascoli theorem, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/spectrum-of-indefinite-integral-operators.

Comment: Your idea is correct: you need to prove that $A$ is continuous from $L^2$ to $W^{1,2}$ to finish the proof.