# Integral operator's norm on space with 1-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory

I'm trying to find the norm of this operator:

$$\begin{aligned}
T:(C[0,1], &||\cdot||_1) &&\rightarrow \quad (C[0,1], ||\cdot||_1) \\
&f &&\mapsto \quad Tf(t):= \int_0^t f(s)ds
\end{aligned}$$

And here's my current progress:
$$\begin{aligned}
||Tf||_1 = \int_0^1 \left| \int_0^tf(s)ds\right|dt &\leq \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^t|f(s)|ds\right) dt \\
&\leq \int_0^1 ||f||_1 dt =||f||_1. 1
\end{aligned}$$

I'm having difficulties to find a function such that $||Tf||_1 = ||f||_1.1$

Any guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Be impulsive, subject to continuity constraints.

Comment: You can't find a function for which the bound is attained, but you can come arbitrarily close.

Comment: This should help $$\int\limits_0^1 \left( \int\limits_0^t|f(s)|ds\right) dt  
=\int\limits_0^1 (1-s)|f(s)|\,ds$$

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/spectrum-of-indefinite-integral-operators