# Norm of Volterra operator in $(C[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_p)$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory

I'm learning about bounded operators and need to compute the norm of the following:

> The operator $V:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ defined by $$(Vf)(t)=\int_0^t f(s)\ ds \qquad t\in [0,1];$$  here $C[0,1]$ is equipped with $\lVert\cdot\rVert_p$ for $p\in [1,\infty)$.

**My attempt:** Using Hölder's inequality,
\begin{align}
\lVert Vf\rVert_p^p & = \int_0^1 |(Vf)(t)|^p\ dt \\
& =\int_0^1 \left|\int_0^t f(s)\ ds\right|^p\ dt\\
&\leq \int_0^1 \left[\int_0^t |f(s)|\ ds\right]^p\ dt\\ 
&\leq \int_0^1\lVert f\rVert_p^p\,\lVert\mathbf{1}\rVert_q^p \ dt\\
&=\lVert f\rVert^p,
\end{align}
here $q$ is the conjugate exponent of $p$ and $\mathbf{1}$ is the constant one function. Thus $V$ is bounded and $\,\lVert V\rVert\leqslant1$.

On the other hand,
\begin{align}
\lVert V\mathbf{1}\rVert_p^p & = \int_0^1 |(V\mathbf{1})(t)|^p\ dt \\
& =\int_0^1 \left|\int_0^t \mathbf{1}(s)\ ds\right|^p\ dt\\
& =\int_0^1 t^p\ dt\\
&=\frac{1}{p+1}.
\end{align}
So $\,\lVert V\mathbf{1}\rVert_p = \left(\frac{1}{p+1}\right)^{1/p}\ge 1$. Thus, $\lVert V\rVert\geqslant1$.

It follows that $\lVert V\rVert=1$.

Comment: I don't think the $p$th root of $1/(p+1)$ is $\ge 1$ generally. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Oops, you're right. How do I fix this?

Comment: When you apply the Hölder inequality you can restrict it to the interval $[0,t].$ This should give a better estimate.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Then I obtain $||V|| \le \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1/p}$. How do I obtain the reverse inequality?

Comment: I think it is not an easy task. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/spectrum-of-indefinite-integral-operators/151444#151444)

Comment: Confirming @RyszardSzwarc's comment that this is not so easy...