Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a operator in $L^2[0,1]$
Find the eigenvalue and eigenvector of $T: L^2[0,1] \to  L^2[0,1]$ given by
$$\forall x\in [0,1],\forall f\in L^2[0,1],\ (Tf)(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$
I already check that $ T \in \mathcal{LC}(L^2[0,1])$, $\|T\|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and that $T$ is injective, ie, 0 is not an eigenvalue. So, if $VP(T)$ is the set of all eigenvectors and $\sigma(T)$ is his spectrum, then $VP(T) \subseteq \sigma(T) \subseteq [-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}]$, meaning the eigenvalues need to be on $[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}]$.
If $\lambda \in VP(T)$, then $(Tf)(x)=\lambda f(x)$ which yields to the differential equation $f(x)=\lambda f'(x)$, then $f(x)=Ke^{x/\lambda}$ and now im stuck, what is next?

Hint: Any eigenvector $f$ must be a continuous function and furthermore $f(0) = 0$. Is any solution of the differential equation satisfying this?

If$f(0)=0$, certainly the exponential is not an eigenvector, then the only continuos function that pops right now is the zero function

Indeed, there are no eigenvectors as the only possibility is the zero function.

Also, a few other corrections: the operator norm of $T$ is actually $2/\pi$ instead of $1/\sqrt{3}$. (See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151444/465145) And, since $T$ is not self-adjoint, you can’t conclude from $|T| = 2/\pi$ that $\sigma(T) \subset [-2/\pi, 2/\pi]$. (Though that happened to be true - in fact, because $T$ is compact but has no eigenvalue, $\sigma(T) = {0}$.)
